# How to bind to a combobox control without add code to the code behind in Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, data-binding, combobox

I am trying to find the most elegant way I can use to bind to a combobox on a Windows Form without using code behind. On the form I have a combobox with two binding sources. One is bound to a Controller, which contains a List of Countries and when called populates this list. The other binding source is bound to the other binding source bound to the controller and I have set the data members as the collection of 'Countries'. I am using EF5 to fetch my data in the controller. However, from what I have done I cannot get the combobox populated when I run my application. Please assist on what I am missing in terms of databind? Please find my code below:

```
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
            Modules.RegisterModules(container);

            var controller = container.Resolve<IController>();
            Application.Run(new TestForm(controller));
        }
    }

    internal static class Modules
    {
        public static void RegisterModules(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            container.RegisterType<IController, GeoController>();
            container.RegisterType<IModelContainer, GeoModelContainer>();
        }
    }

    public class GeoController : IController, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private List<Continent> _continents;
        private List<Country> _countries;
        private List<City> _cities;
        IModelContainer Container { get; set; }

        public GeoController(IModelContainer container)
        {
            Container = container;

            Countries = Container.Countries.ToList();
        }

        #region Properties    

        public List<Country> Countries
        {
            get { return _countries; }
            set
            {
                _countries = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        #endregion


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public interface IController
    {
        List<Country> Countries { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class TestForm : Form
    {
        IController Controller { get; set; }
        public TestForm(IController controller)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Controller = controller;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Winforms binding actually works quite well for example BindingList works well for binding Comboboxes

Comment: @DJKRAZE Ok, then give the OP a solution on how to bind without using code behind. in XAML there's a thing called `{Binding}`, you know

Comment: is this WinForms ..? or WPF based on his tags I don't see anything that indicates that this is XAML / WPF etc

Comment: Sorry, Winforms. I thought it would be clear from Main method and the fact that the comboboxes are on a Windows Form. I know how to do this in WPF but would like a solution for a windows form scenario as this is the user requirement I am dealing with.

Comment: You said you want a solution that doesn't use code behind, but Windows Forms apps do not use markup at all; it's all code.  You've got your terminologies confused.

Comment: Basically, the question is , Is there anyway of binding data to a combobox without having to do this on the TestForm.cs class constructor/method e.g this.countryBindingSource.DataSource = dbContext.Countries.ToList();